# How to understand output of top command

Tags: cpu-usage, top, zombie

How to understand output for top as Load Average is continuously increasing but can't understand which process is eating cpu because %cpu utilization for process is maximum 0.7 but load average is showing high values ! So how to know where is bottleneck !

```
#top 

top - 06:47:14 up 302 days, 21:14,  5 users,  load average: 151.51, 142.09, 116.27
Tasks: 570 total,   1 running, 568 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.5 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 99.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3838696 total,  3221216 used,   617480 free,    67004 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   349404 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                           
 7188 mysql     20   0 1794140 266584   1084 S   0.7  6.9 511:44.15 mysqld                                                            
 7591 ubuntu    20   0   23964   2008   1176 R   0.7  0.1   0:08.87 top                                                               
10983 root      20   0  277124  20132   1252 S   0.7  0.5 634:22.01 php                                                               
 3382 root      20   0  282768  22020   1828 S   0.3  0.6 126:43.32 php                                                               
 8570 root      20   0   17872    180      0 S   0.3  0.0 172:52.24 wrapper                                                           
 8572 root      20   0 1958428 479468    304 S   0.3 12.5 538:40.04 java                                                              
11043 root      20   0  277116  20020   1232 S   0.3  0.5 361:08.73 php                                                               
    1 root      20   0   37344   5944    760 S   0.0  0.2  11:53.34 init                                                              
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.09 kthreadd                                                          
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:18.23 ksoftirqd/0                                                       
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                      
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  46:22.19 rcu_sched                                                         
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  38:55.10 rcuos/0
```

Comment: "99.0 wa" - actually your CPU is not idle at all... the wait value is extremely high and it seems there is probably something wrong with your disk I/O

Comment: You have a high iowait. I suggest you install iotop to see which processes cause that much I/O.

Comment: #iotop 

Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                
 4096 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/1:0]
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]

Comment: `iotop -a` will show accumulated usage since `iotop` was started. That is often more useful than the default output. Also if there is a hardware problem, you may be able to find hints with `dmesg`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can see the out put of the top there is only 1 process running 1 in zombie &  568 are in sleeping & it seems that there is a Java process which might the culprits for the load check the pmap

Comment: I will reframe my question !

Comment: What information should i add or reframe this question in order to come out of ban ;(